# How to generate color based on the magnitude of the values in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to make a Bar plot in python so that the color of each bar is set based on the magnitude of that value. For example the list below is our numbers:

```
List = [2,10,18,50, 100, ... 500]
```

In this situation 2 should have the lightest color and 500 should have the darkest color values. The picture below which is from excel shows what i mean:

[image]

I appreciate answers which helps me.
Thank you.

**Update:**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

names= ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
counts = [30, 40, 55, 100]
bar_colors = ['blue']

ax.bar(names, counts,  color=bar_colors)
ax.set_ylabel('Frequency')
ax.set_title('Names')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Did you already have tried anything? Please, post an excerpt of code to generate the bars chart you already have, and we can try to help you on the colouring task.

Comment: @fernandezr yes of course i have done something. my problem is that i dont know how to generate colors based on the frequency value. I put the code in Update section

Comment: @fernandezr I should mention that the contents of list is not static.I mean the list can be any size

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Then you can use a [Colormap](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colormap-manipulation.html) ([extra docs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.Colormap.html)) from matplotlib

In this example the `bar_colors` list is being creating with a scale between 0 and 100 but you can choose the scale as you want.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

names= ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
counts = [10, 30, 40, 55, 100]

cmap = matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("", ["red","orange", "green"])

bar_colors = [cmap(c/100) for c in counts]

ax.bar(names, counts,  color=bar_colors)
ax.set_ylabel('Frequency')
ax.set_title('Names')
plt.show()
```

Please, notice you can instantiate the `cmap` with a list of colors as you desire.

Also, be sure that when invoking `cmap()` you just can use a float between [0,1].