# Can a horizontal bar chart colour be mapped to the magnitude of a vector in Python?

Tags: python, plot, colors, gradient

I would like to know if Python can be used to create a horizontal bar plot which is coloured based on the magnitude of a vector.

Specifically, I would like to create a function which takes two vectors of the same length, Time and Magnitude, as inputs and returns a 2D graph of a rectangle (thick bar) spawning the entire length of the X (Time) axis, but the colour of the fill inside the rectangle varies horizontally with the value of the Magnitude vector, just like you would apply a gradient with multiple gradient stops in PowerPoint.

Let's assume the following data:

Time vector = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
Magnitude = [-1, 4, 0, 6, 3]

The bar would be filled with the following colour patterns, from left to right: red, yellow, orange, green, yellow

If it has any importance, the data is provided as two columns of a Pandas dataframe

I tried to use the plotly library Bar plot, but was not succesful, I couldn't even get the bar to display.

I guess one option would be to make a vertical bar plot with all bars the same height and map the colour for each bar according to the corresponding Magnitude values.

Thus far the only reference I have is this post:

[How to generate color based on the magnitude of the values in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73905610/how-to-generate-color-based-on-the-magnitude-of-the-values-in-python)

Would prefer using plotly, if that would be possible.

Solved! The solution is as follows:

```
import plotly.io as pio

def Bar_plot(TimeVector, MagnitudeVector):

# Create the plot figure

    fig = go.Figure(data = go.Scatter(

    x = TimeVector,
    y = [0]*len(MagnitudeVector),
    mode = 'markers',
    marker = dict(
        size = 20,
        color = MagnitudeVector,
        colorscale = 'RdYlGn',
        opacity = 1
        )
     ))

# Display the plot

    fig.show()
```

In order to obtain a gradient effect, the magnitude vector should have a somewhat linear behaviour (i.e. not like the results of a step function).

Thanks a lot!